# Linear maps that are matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If I have the linear map $A:\Bbb{R}^3\rightarrow \Bbb{R}^3$ where $A$ is a matrix. Is the matrix $A$  (along with the vectors it operates on) in a basis or not? I think it is not, since the vectors it operators on are not coordinate vectors but rather 'normal' column vectors in   $\Bbb{R}^3$. I do, however, note that if I am correct in my suggestion that it is not in a particular basis, then if we where to represent $A$ in the basis $(\mathbf{e}_1,\mathbf{e}_2,\mathbf{e}_3)$ then the matrix representing $A$ would have the same components as $A$ but act on coordinate vectors rather then the 'normal' column 
vectors. Am I correct?

**EDIT:**

I will try to make my point clearer.

If we have a linear map $f:V\rightarrow W$ we can represent this map with a matrix $A$ (sorry I have changed notation here, $A$ now no longer represents the linear map). This can b represented on the following  commutative diagram:
[image]
We have coordinate vectors in $F^n$ and $F^m$ (these represent the proper vectors in a certain basis) and proper vectors  are in $V$ and $W$. The maps $g_1$ and $g_2$ are coordinate maps.

$A$ is the representing matrix of $f$ in a particular bias (or two bases, the basis of $F^n$ and $F^m$).

$f$ is not associated with a basis for a normal linear map.

My question is simply if $f$ is itself a matrix, then surly the above comment about not been associated with a still holds?

**Example**
The linear map $B:\Bbb{R}^2\rightarrow \Bbb{R}^2$ is defined by the matrix
$$  B= \begin{pmatrix}
        1& 0  \\
        0 & -2 \\ 
        \end{pmatrix} $$
We can represent this linear map in terms of the basis $((1,2)^T,(-1,1)^T)$ as follows:
$$  B'= \begin{pmatrix}
        -1& -1  \\
        -2 & 0 \\ 
        \end{pmatrix} $$
So it is clear that $B'$ has an associated basis, but I don't think the matrix $B$ does?

Comment: What do you mean by "in a basis"? What do you mean by "act on"?

Comment: @darijgrinberg I mean that it does not have an associated set of basis vectors, and that if for example we did the operation $A'=PAP^{-1}$ the matrices $P$ would represent coordinate maps rather then change-of-bias matrices

Comment: Matrices don't tend to have "associated sets of basis vectors". I don't know what "coordinate maps" are. A "change-of-basis(!) matrix" is defined when you have two bases of the same space; I don't see what it relates to in your question. Sadly it seems your confusion with notation is preventing you from asking a clear question, and I can second user7530's recommendation to read a textbook. (I have recently found http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~gill/CILASite/ , which seems to be a good text despite the egregious typesetting.)

Comment: @darijgrinberg see edit

Comment: OK, that makes more sense. By "$f$ is itself a matrix", do you mean "there exists a fixed matrix $F$ such that for every column vector $v$, we have $f\left(v\right) = Fv$"? In this case, this matrix $F$ represents the map $f$ with respect to the standard bases of $F^n$ and $F^m$ (that is, the bases consisting of the column vectors with one $1$ entry and the remaining entries being $0$). If you want to represent the map $f$ with respect to some other bases, you need to multiply $F$ by some base-change matrices.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I have added an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A matrix is just a bucket of numbers. It's not a linear map until you pick a basis for the domain and codomain vector spaces (at which point *every* linear map can be written as a matrix in that basis, and every matrix represents a linear map). Sometimes we write down $3\times 3$ matrices and call them linear maps from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to itself without explicitly naming the basis; when we do so we are implicitly picking the Cartesian basis.

So yes, if you interpret a matrix to be a linear map, you *must* also have a basis (or two bases) in mind. That's the only way the matrix can act on elements of the vector space.

EDIT:

If you have vector spaces $V_1$ and $V_2$, you can find a basis $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ for $V_1$ and $w_1, \ldots, w_m$ for $V_2$, and then can represent every element of $V_1$ using $n$ numbers $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n$ as the sum $\sum_i \alpha_i v_i$, and similarly for $V_2$ and $m$ numbers $\beta_1, \ldots, \beta_m$.

A linear map, written in the bases $\{a_i\}$ and $\{b_i\}$, *acts on the coefficients* $\alpha_i$ and transforms them into coefficients $\beta_i$. If you pick different bases, you will get different matrices even for the *same* linear map.

Any good linear algebra textbook should cover this concept in much greater detail and with many examples.

Comment: When we talk about bias, we associate them with coordinate vectors (or vice versa) but the vectors $A$ (say) operates on are not coordinate vectors, they are actually vectors (since linear maps act on vectors) and thus cannot be part of a bias?